# How to parse 「単語」をその形の特徴・文の中での働きによって分類したものを「品詞」と言います

Tags: parsing

> この本は日本語教育のために、現代日本語の文法を考える本です。
> この本では「単語」よりも「文」を重視します。ですから、初めから「文」を扱います。現実に日本語を使う場合、「文」が基本の単位になりますし、日本語教育でも、教科書の第一課から「文」の形で入っていくことが多いからです。日本語にはどんな「文」の型、「文型」があるのかを考えます。
> **「単語」をその形の特徴・文の中での働きによって分類したものを「品詞」と言います。**

When it comes to the ・ symbol, I'm assuming that it shows the part before and after it as alternatives. I can understand 文の中での働きによって分類したものを「品詞」と言います

> 文の中での働きによって分類したものを「品詞」と言います - Things classified by their function in a sentence we call 品詞.

However, I am unsure about「単語」をその形の特徴, though - how should I put it in the sentence?

Is it:

> 「単語」をその形の特徴によって分類したものを「品詞」と言います

However, I don't think it makes much sense, there should be a verb there for 「単語」を. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sentence has a number of parts that interrelate in a not-entirely-obvious way.

Here's the whole sentence.

> 「単語【たんご】」をその形【かたち】の特徴【とくちょう】・文【ぶん】の中【なか】での働【はたら】きによって分類【ぶんるい】したものを「品詞【ひんし】」と言【い】います

#### Question 1: Parsing the *nakaguro* 「・」

The *nakaguro* 「・」 symbol does indicate alternatives, as you mention.  It looks like you might have gotten confused about where to parse this.

Let's add parentheses to show the bounds of the two alternatives.

> 「単語【たんご】」を**（その形【かたち】の特徴【とくちょう】・文【ぶん】の中【なか】での働【はたら】き）**によって分類【ぶんるい】したものを「品詞【ひんし】」と言【い】います

How do we know to omit the 「単語【たんご】」を from the two alternatives?

This leads right into your second question.

#### Question 2: The verb for that 「単語【たんご】」を

We see from that を that this noun requires a transitive verb.  Sometimes that verb is omitted and implied, which complicates things.  However, here, we have the verb explicitly included.

Let's break it down.

Here's what the sentence looks like when we chop out everything but that object noun and its verb:

> **「単語【たんご】」を**その形【かたち】の特徴【とくちょう】・文【ぶん】の中【なか】での働【はたら】きによって**分類【ぶんるい】した**ものを「品詞【ひんし】」と言【い】います

↓

> **「単語【たんご】」を**　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　**分類【ぶんるい】した**

The bit between を and 分類【ぶんるい】した tells us more detail about *how* the 分類【ぶんるい】 happens: によって (by means of, via) the two alternatives separated by the 「・」 *nakaguro*.

#### Relative clauses and modifiers

Note that everything up through the 分類【ぶんるい】した is itself a relative clause modifying the word もの, giving us more detail about that もの -- what kind of もの (thing) it is that we 言【い】います (call) a 「品詞【ひんし】」 ("part of speech").

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a clear overview of the breakdown. So the もの is "words that we classify by the characteristics of the form/function in a sentence"? Does that sound about right?

Comment: @firuvi, yes. In translation, I'd probably avoid the slash and construct it a little differently to avoid ambiguity -- _"words that we classify by the characteristics of their form, or by their function in a sentence"_.  With just the slash, it sounds like _"... by the characteristics of the [form or function] in a sentence"_, which doesn't quite convey the meaning of the source text.

Comment: It took me a while to realize the dots weren't something on my screen... So tried adding something to make them more obvious. Not sure this is to your liking...

Comment: @EddieKal, I like that, it makes the text clearer.  I'll do that in future (using the _kagi kakko_). ;)